# How to know the pair of key that return from array_intersec

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I have these array :

```
$a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$b = ['d','e','f'];
```

if I use array_intersect to the array above like,

```
$c = array_intersect($a, $b);
$d = array_intersect($b,$a);
```

$c will return :

```
Array
(
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
)
```

and $d will return :

```
Array
(
    [0] => d
    [1] => e
    [2] => f
)
```

How can I know the pair of key of those array_intersection like,

```
[3] --> [0]
[4] --> [1]
[5] --> [2]
```

I mean, the index [3] of array `$a` is intersected with index [0] in array `$b`. how can I know that ??

Thank you very much.

Comment: Selected answer is time consuming because of  `array_search()` :- https://eval.in/768069  (check time)against mine answer link (https://eval.in/768032). Not needed actually. Will become more handy if array length increased.

Comment: `foreach()` and `array_search()`? not a good approach (talking about the answer selected by OP). more time consuming :-  https://eval.in/768069 (check time) against mine answer link (https://eval.in/768032). Not needed to do in that fashion. Will become more handy if array length increased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
$b = ['d', 'e', 'm', 'f'];
$intersect = array_intersect($a, $b);
$key_intersect = [];
foreach ($intersect as $key => $value) {
    $key_intersect[$key] = array_search($value, $b);
}
var_dump($key_intersect);
```

In `array $b` i have inserted an extra element to check if it works perfectly even if there is some element left.

Comment: time consuming because of  `array_search()` :- https://eval.in/768069  (check time). Not needed actually. Will become more handy if array length increased.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want like this:-

```
<?php

$a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
$b = ['d','e','f'];
$c=  array_intersect( $a,$b);
$d=  array_intersect( $b,$a);
$intersection_keys_array = array_combine (array_keys($c),array_keys($d)); // combine $c and $d so that $c values become key and $d values become values in resultant array
print_r($intersection_keys_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/768032

Or

A bit more fancy output:- https://eval.in/768033